# Accessing Attribute of an Array within an Array using ngFor

Tags: typescript, ngfor

Essentially what I'm trying to do is add attributes to a table in Angular. The problem is that the attributes are nested in an array which is located within an array.

I'm assuming that this problem is solved by using a few `*ngFor` directives at a time, but I can't quite figure out the proper syntax.

What it sums up to is there is an array of Students. Each student in that array has their own array of Grades. Each grade in that array has an object called "theAssignment". Each assignment has an attribute of "type". What I want to accomplish is to have each assignment's type added to a cell in the table.
Here is some of the JSON to help visualize the structure:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
    accessLevel: "Student"
    conductLevel: "Average"
    dob: -269640000000
    email: "lt@gmail.com"
    firstName: "Luis"
    gradeLevel: "Senior"
 grades: Array(4)
0:
    gradeID: 2
    pointsEarned: 80
    theAssignment:
        id: 1
        type: "Test"
```

I believe this code sums up what I'm trying to do (although, obviously you cannot have multiple directives in one tag, and this could be way off-base):

```
<th scope="row" *ngFor="let student of students" *ngFor="let 
grades of student.grades" *ngFor="let grade of grades">{{ 
grade.theAssignment.type }}</th>
```

I know how to make a single `*ngFor` directive work properly, but adding this many layers adds a complexity that I'm not yet comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it in an ng container inside your main loop and access the property on the object

```
<ng-container
 *ngFor=“let grade of student.grades”>

</ng-container>
```